# Move on form submit from /page to /page/<input> in Express.js / Node.js

Tags: javascript, forms, express, submit

When user types a `nickname` into a input and clicks submit I want to move him from `/page` to `/page/:nickname` in Express. How do i do this?

My code:

```
// app.js

app.get("/page", (request, response) => {
    response.render("page", 
    });
});

app.get("/page/:nickname", (request, response) => {
    response.render("page", {
        nickname: request.params.nickname
    });
});
```

````
// page.pug
extends layout

block content
    // render when on "/page" and "/page/:nickname"
    form(method="post" action="???")
        input(placeholder="Player nickname" type="text")
        button.btn.btn-success(type="submit")
            |Search
    if nickname
        // render if on "/page/:nickname"```
````

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can take to this:

### Server-side

The form should be GET instead of POST since you aren't changing anything on the server. You also need to give the input a name.

```
<form action="/page" method="GET">
```

Submit the form as normal. The browser will navigate to:

```
/page?name_of_input=what_the_user_entered
```

On the server read `req.query.name_of_input` and then generate a redirect response:

```
res.redirect(301, `/page/${encodeURIComponent(req.query.name_of_input)}`)
```

### Client-side

Use an event listener to cancel the default behaviour of the form, and navigate to the desired URL by assigning it to `location`.

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    location = `/page/${encodeURIComponent(document.querySelector('input').value)}`
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Write in the action the /page and send the nickname with the name="" tag. You can use the name with req.params.nickname.